# How to take nth item in array to zth item in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I created an array like this:

```
string[] test = new string[]{"apple", "banana", "tomato", "pineapple", "grapes"};
```

And now, I would like to take the 2nd, 3rd and the 4th item in the array and join together, currently I'm using this code:

```
string result = "";
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    result += test[i] + " ";
}
```

So the result would be `banana tomato pineapple` and this works fine.

And I would like to ask if there's a standard or better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write it more succinctly like this:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", test.Skip(1).Take(3));
```

Also, this has the bonus of not adding a trailing space (which your code does).

Comment: Word of caution that linq's `Skip` method is not optimized for indexed collections (arrays, lists..). If performance is a concern, better to use a custom Slice / Range extension method (similar to your existing code) for arrays or switch to using a `List<string>` and the `GetRange` method. The string.Join method is still preferable.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, which uses `GetRange`, which is very natural for this:

```
var result = String.Join(" ", test.ToList().GetRange(1, 3));
```

Comment: Note that the `ToList` creates a copy of the array. Utterly irrelevant with 5 items, but good to know if your array was going to be big.

Comment: Yes, if you have a large array you should be careful with this solution, as @Blorgbeard rightly says.

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple solution.

```
string result = "";
for(int i = 0; i <= [upper bound] ; i++)
{
    if i >= [n] and i <= [z] then
    {
        result += test[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

You can set `n` and `z` as range as you want.

Comment: This answer seems to have added complexity to OP's code rather than simplifying. You don't need to loop over the entire array and check whether you're in range each time; just loop from `n` to `z` - then you don't need an `if`.